# ASP.NET (MVC) Session Timeout - Reset Timeout - Is my understanding of this correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically I need to create a client side "Your session is about to expire....click here to Stay Logged in..." (aynchronous without page redirect)

If I create a controller with a stub EmptyResult action "ResetTimeout" then will any calls into this *empty* action method stub automatically reset the session timer? Is there a "standard" way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, any request from the browser (that carries the cookie to identify the session) will reset the session timer.

(The request doesn't even have to go so far as to being handled by a controller, as long as it has gone far enough that the session is identified.)

A request is normally always returning a response, so you can just as well return something like a plain string from the action method, that you can look for when the browser handles the response.

Comment: So for my situation is there a way to check the server to see if a user has timed out from the client without updating the session timeout?

Comment: @Joshua Enfield: Not easily. You would have to make a request to a sessionless page so that it wouldn't affect the user's session, and keep your own record of the sessions on the server to find out when that user last accessed a page.